# How to reference a cell value inside a string in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a list of movie titles and want to take a movie title from a cell and query imdb.

How do I replace "Goonies" with my cell reference?

Here is my VBA macro.

```
Sub MovieLookup()
On Error Resume Next

    Dim objHttp As Object
    Dim Movie As String

    Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    objHttp.Open "GET", "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=apikeyhere&t=Goonies", False
    objHttp.send ""
    Movie = objHttp.responseText

    Cells(1, 1).Value = Movie

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it OK to show the `apikey` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace "Goonies" with a cell reference like `Range("A1").Value2`. Here is how that would look in your case:

```
objHttp.Open "GET", "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=ffe8bdc5&t=" & Range("A1").Value2, False
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have it this way: Use `InputBox` to get movie title and concatenate it with your base URL without movie title.

Updated code:

```
Sub MovieLookup()
On Error Resume Next

Dim objHttp As Object
Dim movieTitle as string
dim movieURL as string

    'Get movie name
    movieTitle = InputBox("Please enter movie title:")

    'Replace single space (" ") with plus sign ("+")
    movieTitle = Replace(movieTitle , " ", "+")

    'Create movieURL
    movieURL = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=ffe8bdc5&t=" & movieTitle 

    Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    objHttp.Open "GET", movieURL, False
    objHttp.send ""
    Movie = objHttp.responseText

    Cells(1, 1).Value = Movie
End Sub
```